# Pretty new to making discord bots, and I need help on an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm on node version 16.9.1 and Discord.js 13.1.0, I am coding on VSC
this is my code:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('started');
});


client.login(token)
```

When I tried to start my bot with node . or node main.js it is supposed to output "started" in the console however it does nothing and gives me an error instead. Here is the error:

[error I was given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5xUU.png)

Comment: Are you running this on your school network? The error suggests an SSL issue - looks like securly.com are intercepting the connection to discord?

Comment: As madebydavid said, this is a DNS/SSL issue, are you using a private network?
Something is blocking and/or intercepting the site, if this is a school network there's a high likelihood Discord's domain is blocked.
Try again on a private network perhaps?

Comment: Yeah it might be thanks